# Semicolon in probability expression

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I run in to this formula when reading a tutorial:

$$ \begin{align}
P(\pi|\mathbf L;\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi0}) & =P(\mathbf L|\pi)P(\pi|\gamma_{\pi1},\gamma_{\pi0})\tag{28} \\
&\propto [\pi^{C_1}(1-\pi)^{C_0}][\pi^{\gamma_{\pi1}-1}(1-\pi)^{\gamma_{\pi0}-1}]\tag{29}\\
&\propto\pi^{C_1+\gamma_{\pi1}-1}(1-\pi)^{C_0+\gamma_{\pi0}-1}\tag{30}
\end{align}
$$

I was just wondering for formula (28), if we get the left side from the right side, why the left side of equation is $P(\pi \mid \mathbf L;\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi2})$ instead of $P(\mathbf L \mid \gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi2})$ (according to the chain rule)?

Edit: This is the [link of the tutorial](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~resnik/pubs/LAMP-TR-153.pdf). Basically, this is to derive a Gibbs sampler for Naive Bayes model and Figure 4 is the plate representation of its graphical model. $\pi \sim Beta(\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi2})$, $L \sim Bernoulli(\pi)$. $C_{0}$ and $C_{1}$ denote all documents with negative label and all documents with positive label respectively.

Comment: I've edited your question to use Mathjax in place of the image. Please review that it still says what you intend. A tutorial for mathjax can be found here. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Exactly how does this tutorial define or describe the key objects in your question, including $\pi$, $\mathbf{L}$, and the $C_i$?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for letting me know. This is the link of the tutorial http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~resnik/pubs/LAMP-TR-153.pdf You can find the graphical model in Figure 4. Basically, this is to derive a Gibbs sampler for Naive Bayes model. $\pi \sim Beta(\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi2})$, $L \sim Bernoulli(\pi)$

Comment: @user777 Thank you very much for editing it :)

Comment: That description of $\mathbf{L}$ seems inconsistent with its use in the equations. It appears instead that $\mathbf{L}$ might be synonymous with the ordered pair $(C_0,C_1)$ of counts of failures and successes, respectively, in $C_0+C_1$ independent Bernoulli$(\pi)$ trials. I suppose if $C_0+C_1=1$ then the description of $\mathbf{L}$ as Bernoulli would be accurate, but I cannot determine that because I still don't know what $C_0$ and $C_1$ might be. It would be strange to use two variables in that way to represent a single 0/1 outcome.

Comment: @whuber I suppose $C_0$ and $C_1$ are not "values", they denotes all documents with negative label and all documents with positive label respectively. A document is a set of words.

Comment: In that case the formulas would make no sense whatsoever: you cannot exponentiate *numbers* like $\pi$ and $1-\pi$ with values that are "documents." In fact, the tutorial's Figure 3 helpfully provides a list of descriptions, including that $C_0$ and $C_1$ are "number(s) of documents labeled 0 (1)." This confirms my previous guess. Later they describe $\mathbf{L}$ as a "specific sequence ... of ... binary labels." These descriptions are important clarifications which you should consider incorporating in your question.

Answer (score -3):

This is a [Bayes theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) application, as in: $$P(A|B)\sim P(B|A)P(A)$$

The semicolon separates the parameters, in your case it's $\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi0}$. So the Equation 28 has in the right side the probability distribution of $\pi$ given the parameters $\gamma_{\pi1}, \gamma_{\pi0}$ denoted as: $P(\pi|\gamma_{\pi1},\gamma_{\pi0})$. So, you can map $A=L$, $B=\pi$ to see how the Bayes theorem is applied here.

Comment: While I agree that you answer is correct, I think additional explanation is needed. In particular, I think you'd need to explain where the gammas are (implicitly) in the first term on the right, and why they're not written there. [I can imagine a reader could be likely to try to associate them either with A or with B in your answer, and become confused.]